# Kendo UI Menu jumping when menu is clicked

Tags: user-interface, menu, kendo-ui

I have my menu set to:

```
.CloseOnClick(true)
.OpenOnClick(true)
```

(I am using MVC4 with Razor syntax)

When I click on a menu item, it opens the menu content, but when I click on the menu item again, the screen jumps down the page when it's not supposed to. I can't figure out why the screen is jumping.

Here is the code in question that is triggered:

```
items.Add().Text("Stores")
    .Content(@<text>
    <h2>Around the Globe</h2>
    </text>);
```

It seems the screen is jumping because of the `.Content()` parameter.

Also, before the menu is clicked, the URL is:

```
http://localhost:55656/HelloWorld
```

But after it is pressed the URL changes to:

```
http://localhost:55656/HelloWorld#Menu-2
```

Although nothing changes besides the Kendo UI Menu opening up, it's not until it's pressed again that the screen jumps.

Comment: I know little about this control.  Does the generated page source have an &lt;a&gt; elenet with a name attribute value of "Menu-2"?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the Menu is navigating on click. This should only happen if you intend the item to navigate () or if you have a JavaScript error on the page and the click on the item is not prevented. Can you check if there really is an error and post it here?

Comment: I don't think there is an error, I think it is trying to navigate.

Comment: I looked at the generated HTML code and I noticed that the menu item has this code:
<a class="k-link" href="#Menu-1">

I am guessing the href is what is making the page jump, but I am not sure what is generating the href, so I don't know how to fix it. Is it Kendo UI, MVC, or something in the CSS that is generating it? I can't find any reference to href in my code that could be generating this issue.

Comment: Can you share a sample page where we can see what is happening?

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry I am new to web development. Currently, I am just running from my localbox. 

If you just create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Web App and implement the Kendo UI Menu index.cshtml from:
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/menu/index.html

When you click on the 'Stores' Menu, it should make the screen jump (aka. scroll down) to where the Menu is, but it really shouldn't be doing that.

In the HTML, there are 2 references to Menu-2:
1. <a class="k-link" href="#Menu-2">Stores<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s"></span></a>

2. <div id="Menu-2" class="k-content">

Comment: Looks like a bug - an anchor tag is always generated when the item has content, even when the anchor tag is not needed in this case. To work around that, you can add a click event handler on the item and prevent it, thus stopping the navigation.

We will investigate how we can fix the issue for the next release.